# How to extent activrerecord,just make id to id.to_i

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Mixin

    alias old_id id

    def id
      old_id.to_i
    end

    def hello
      "hellooooooooooooo"
    end

  end
end


ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ActiveRecord::Mixin
```

I make is because:

id column in oracle is number type,not number(10), @user.id return 123.0,not 123,so I would like to do it by extend ar.

But my way above does not work for me,it still show number with dot zero,123.0.

How to make id auto invove id.to_i???

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def new_id
  return self.to_i
end
```

Then

```
@user.new_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `alias_method_chain` ([docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_method_chain)):

```
def id_with_oracle
  id_without_oracle.to_i
end
alias_method_chain :id, :oracle
```

But this may not work. As the `id` function is dynamically generated from the `method_missing` magic of ActiveRecord.